# crash-tool doesn't work on Ubuntu with kernel v5.3.15

Tags: 18.04, kernel, crash

Recently, I upgraded the kernel version to v5.3.15 on Ubuntu 18.04. When using the crash tool, I found that it was unable to analyze the dump file. The log is as follows.

```
log:
  root@node:/var/crash# crash  vmlinux  /var/crash/201912251143/dump.201912251143
  crash 7.2.7++
  Copyright (C) 2002-2019  Red Hat, Inc.
  Copyright (C) 2004, 2005, 2006, 2010  IBM Corporation
  Copyright (C) 1999-2006  Hewlett-Packard Co
  Copyright (C) 2005, 2006, 2011, 2012  Fujitsu Limited
  Copyright (C) 2006, 2007  VA Linux Systems Japan K.K.
  Copyright (C) 2005, 2011  NEC Corporation
  Copyright (C) 1999, 2002, 2007  Silicon Graphics, Inc.
  Copyright (C) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002  Mission Critical Linux, Inc.
  This program is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License,
  and you are welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under
  certain conditions.  Enter "help copying" to see the conditions.
  This program has absolutely no warranty.  Enter "help warranty" for details.

  GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
  Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
  This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
  There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
  and "show warranty" for details.
  This GDB was configured as "aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu"...

  crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffff0000124d4e58  type: "shadow_timekeeper xtime_sec"
  crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffff000012094a78  type: "pv_ops"
  crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffff801fb9de0058  type: "IRQ stack pointer"
  crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffff801fb9fc2058  type: "IRQ stack pointer"
  crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffff801fba1a4058  type: "IRQ stack pointer"
  crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffff801fba386058  type: "IRQ stack pointer"
  crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffff801fba568058  type: "IRQ stack pointer"
  crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffff801fba74a058  type: "IRQ stack pointer"
  crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffff801fba92c058  type: "IRQ stack pointer"
  ....
  crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffff80af9ba1e058  type: "IRQ stack pointer"
  crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffff000012531478  type: "high_memory"
```

I will back the kernel version to v5.0.0, manually trigger the crash, use crash to analyze the dump file, and it works normally.
I don't know the reason, help me.

```
environment:
  root@node:/var/crash# lsb
  lsblk        lsb_release
  root@node:/var/crash# lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
  Release:        18.04
  Codename:       bionic
  root@node:/var/crash# file /bin/ls
  /bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=de05fcef79d88af9cf9a71ed38e73af0b179bfb2, stripped
  root@k8snode:/var/crash# dpkg -l | grep kexe
  ii  kexec-tools                                                  1:2.0.16-1ubuntu1.1                    arm64        tools to support fast kexec reboots
  root@node:/var/crash#


crash with -d8 It seems that there is a problem with parsing.

read_diskdump: PAGE_EXCLUDED: paddr/pfn: 24d4e58/24d4 crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffff0000124d4e58 type: "shadow_timekeeper xtime_sec" xtime timespec.tv_sec: fffffa943b10: Wed Jan 20 03:10:08 8921554 read_diskdump: paddr/pfn: 1e17dec/1e17 -> cache physical page: 1e17000 utsname: sysname: Linux nodename: k8snode release: 5.3.15-050315.2019121301-generic version: #appstream SMP PREEMPT Tue Dec 24 16:06:52 CST 2019 machine: aarch64 domainname: (none) base kernel version: 5.3.15 ....

debug the living the v5.3.15 , the crash tool work well. root@node:/var/crash# crash vmlinux /proc/kcore

crash 7.2.7++ Copyright (C) 2002-2019 Red Hat, Inc. Copyright (C) 2004, 2005, 2006, 2010 IBM Corporation Copyright (C) 1999-2006 Hewlett-Packard Co Copyright (C) 2005, 2006, 2011, 2012 Fujitsu Limited Copyright (C) 2006, 2007 VA Linux Systems Japan K.K. Copyright (C) 2005, 2011 NEC Corporation Copyright (C) 1999, 2002, 2007 Silicon Graphics, Inc. Copyright (C) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002 Mission Critical Linux, Inc. This program is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions. Enter "help copying" to see the conditions. This program has absolutely no warranty. Enter "help warranty" for details.

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6 Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details. This GDB was configured as "aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu"...

  KERNEL: vmlinux
DUMPFILE: /proc/kcore
    CPUS: 64
    DATE: Thu Jan  2 16:20:24 2020
  UPTIME: 02:02:33

LOAD AVERAGE: 0.57, 0.28, 0.21 TASKS: 1121 NODENAME: k8snode RELEASE: 5.3.15-050315.2019121301-generic VERSION: #appstream SMP PREEMPT Tue Dec 24 16:06:52 CST 2019 MACHINE: aarch64 (unknown Mhz) MEMORY: 255.7 GB PID: 5588 COMMAND: "crash" TASK: ffff809f97551b00 [THREAD_INFO: ffff809f97551b00] CPU: 63 STATE: TASK_RUNNING (ACTIVE)

crash> ... I think kexec-tools's version is probably old. I install kexec-tools v2.0.20 from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/kernel/kexec/kexec-tools.git. But the same error reporting.
```